# UIImageView goes out of screen when zooming it

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, zooming, scale

I have the current code to enlarge UIImageView:

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{
    mCurrentScale += [pinchGestureRecognizer scale] - mLastScale;
    mLastScale = [pinchGestureRecognizer scale];

    if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        mLastScale = 1.0;

    }

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, mCurrentScale, mCurrentScale);
    thumbView.transform = newTransform;
}
```

Image is located in right corner and if I enlarge half of image gores out of View, how can I enlarge image in that way it stays in right corner and shown properly?

Comment: Pinch zoom is supposed to work on the pinch location, are you asking how to break that and always have your image right aligned?
Try messing with the origin after setting the transform.

Answer (score 0):

use CGAffineTransformTranslate to move it left as you zoom?

Comment: Can you give me an example please?